# Huawei P40 Pro find the initial android firmware

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

Is there any way to find exactly the android version that a Huawei smartphone was preloaded with (at the time It was opened from the box) ?

My Huawei P40 Pro recently got updated by itself and I don't like the new interface. I want to rollback to the initial firmware that was installed when I first turned on the phone.

Maybe it's recorded on log or something similar to * # * # 2846579 # * # * or through it's IMEI code or a code on it's package?

Comment: Operating System: EMUI 10.1 (Based on Android 10), You can see the factory settings of the P40 pro on the [official website](https://consumer.huawei.com/eg-en/phones/p40-pro/specs/).

Comment: @shirley Yes but is there a log

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to downgrade to the initial emui version now as huawei has blocked almost all the possibilities via the software updates. If you are determined to do so, just google downgrade plus your model on xda developer website. Some people mentioned it needs two separate downgrades to reach the initial emui 10 version. I have tried numerous ways to downgrade my p40 pro (C636) to below 10.1.0.135, but got stuck. If I succeed, I would like to post it on xda.